# Comparing two (almost identical) implementations of Insertion Sort; one of them fails

Tags: java, insertion-sort

Basically I replaced `n` with `aData[i]` in the **Non-working** implementation. Am I missing something fundamentally wrong? The Second implementation fails on the same TEST Data.

Passing implementation:

```
static long[] sort(long[] aData) {
    for (int i = 1; i < aData.length; i++) {
        long n = aData[i];

        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && aData[j] > n) {
            aData[j + 1] = aData[j];
            j--;
        }
        aData[j + 1] = n;
    }
    return aData;
}
```

Failing implementation:

```
static long[] sort(long[] aData) {
    for (int i = 1; i < aData.length; i++) {
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && aData[j] > aData[i]) {
            aData[j + 1] = aData[j];
            j--;
        }
        aData[j + 1] = aData[i];
    }
    return aData;
}
```

Comment: The question is down-voted without _reason_ being stated. Good going SO gatekeepers.

Comment: This question was posted without reading and understanding the way this site works.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  Posting code and saying, in effect, "please debug this for me" is considered off-topic.

Comment: Well to be honest almost 95% of the time I ask a question, it is marked as off-topic. I seriously refrain from asking any questions on SO because of the **FEAR** of it being marked as **OFF-TOPIC** by someone or the other. I usually are very careful. This question was down-voted on CR, after that I came to SO, and is down-voted here. In full honesty I don't know where to post a question, because the definition of a _GOOD_ question on SO is very-very subjective. I hope you understand what I am saying.

Comment: I agree that it might have been a bit harsh for people to downvote it that much, but I think a key reason is just saying "Non-working", without telling us what exactly about isn't working. Is it syntax errorring? Is it sorting the first one and then none others? Is it...? Without that I look at this question and I don't know what it is you're expecting from us, and others probably did that too.

Comment: @BenHare - That's a constructive criticism.

Comment: @KunalB please, read [ask] and [mcve]. I agree with Ben Hare. We have very high quality standards on SO.

Comment: You cannot just copy paste code and say "it's broken fix it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first iteration of the while loop, `j + 1 == i`. So when you write `aData[j + 1] = aData[j]`, you change the value of `aData[i]` within the loop.

In the initial version, `n` is constant throughout the operation. Also note that using `aData[i]` instead of `n` is very unlikely to improve performance (if anything, it will probably be slower).